# htaccess "faking subdomains"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been looking at htaccess and how to use rewrite rules in order to make a sort of "fake subdomain" for users.

so far i have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?user=%1
```

this will take any /somthing and make it a subdomain and then pass the subdomain value in as a param to pick up.

i want to be able to now use actual parameters, and pass them through normaly with the extra "user" param from the "subdomain"
e.g.

```
fred.domain.com/index.php?page=1&sort=up
```

would give me in $_GET

```
['user'] = 'fred'
['page']= 1
['sort'] = up
```

but for the life of me I cant figure out how to do this! as when i add any other params, I loose the user bit

Any help? =)

Also any helpful tutorials on htaccess would be nice! as all ones ive found haven't really explained what each bit does and why =\

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use environment variables for such. See the apache documentation for mod_rewrite how to set them or reference them. Additionally you can do that inside your PHP script and the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732366/dynamic-subdomains-in-codeigniter-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file has nothing to do here. It can't help you.
To direct a user to your server, you have to alter DNS record, not web-server config.

Comment: Not quite.  Most domains operated by hosting service provides offer a wild-card subdomain routing.  So my DNS domain has a subdomain catch-all which points at my hosting service \(HS\) load-balance IP,94.136.40.100, as with all other shared hosting account holders.  My HS decodes the HTTP_HOST to point all subdomain at my DOCRROT, and I have to use my DOCROOT `.htaccess` to process the subdomains.  See http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-Webfusion for articles which give more explanation.

Comment: I see nothing in your comment that contradicts with my answer, but thank you for your effort anyway.

Comment: If your HS provider has already set up a wild card DNS entry (as most do), then you've got _nothing_ to do in DNS and _all_ of the configuration is done in your DOCROOT `.htaccess` which kind of makes both of your statements at the least very misleading :(

Comment: I still don't get the point. If you have your DNS setup already, it doesn't mean you don't need it at all. What's misleading here?

Comment: As most SHS providers set up a **\*** DNS A record for each account "you normally ***don't*** have to alter any DNS records." and first step in implementing what the OP wants is to configure his or her `.htaccess` file(s). So both of your points are pretty much 180% out, that's all.  No big issue.  Sorry.

Comment: Okay, okay. You don't have to configure a DNS record if it's already configured. I am not arguing that, you are taking be wrong. There is nothing to configure in the .htaccess though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can set vhost *.yourdomain.com to point to a single path and then use mod_rewrite for the url parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that:

- You own a domain, `domain.com` say, that is being hosted by some shared hosting service (SHS) provider.
- You either have access to a control panel to set up subdomains, or your SHS provider has already set up a ***** A record mapping to its shared service.
- Some SHS providers simply map `*.domain.com` to a fixed subdirectory, say `/webroot/domain.com/public_html`; others do this top level-redirection for their users and provide a control panel which allow account-holders to associate subdomains with specific subdirectories.

So you need to work out which applies in your case:

- by looking at your SHS providers FAQs,
- by trying `http://sss.domain.com/` to see if it routes to your DOCROOT
- by using a `phpinfo()` script to see what Rewrite environment variable it uses to point to your DOCROOT. (For technical reasons in Apache, see [Dynamic mass virtual hosts with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/vhosts.html), %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} cannot be properly initialised for each user, so providers typically use a `RewriteMap` to initialise a stand-in; mine uses %{ENV:DOCUMENT_ROOT_REAL})

So let's assume that you want to set up a blog at say `http://blog.domain.com/`, you may need to:

- Issue permanent redirects **[R=301]** from legacy references to `http://domain.com/blog/*` to `http://blog.domain.com/*`
- Issue *internal* redirects from `http://blog.domain.com/*` to `DOCROOT/blogdir/*`
- Add the necessary conditional interlocks to prevent infinite redirection loops, where this second internal redirect is then treated as a legacy reference.

I could give you a set of rewrite rules to do this, but given that I've answered a dozen flavours of this same Q this months, you can find lots of templates by searching or by looking at my blog ([Webfusion](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-Webfusion), [.htaccess](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-59)) where I've written a number of articles giving more explanation.

If you want a single application to catch some wildcard subset of domain, as long as you can encode this in a regexp then you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    (sompattern)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(?!appdir/).*  appdir/catchall.php?arg=$0&subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

The `(?!appdir/)` bit is called a lookahead negative assertion and this stops the rule refiring on itself.