# htaccess tow subfolder codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i have link:

http://domain.com/app/codeigniter

in file .htaccess of folder codeigniter  i have

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

code of domain is wordpress and i have code file .htaccess

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

but when I visit http://domain.com/app/codeigniter  receive an error message "Page Not found" of wordpress

Comment: where is a question here?

Comment: please check once in your wordpress any posts or pages or category or tags not have "app" slug?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic sub domains codeigniter.

Please visit this stack over flow link found it very use full

[How to implement dynamic subdomains in codeigniter with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732366/dynamic-subdomains-in-codeigniter-with-htaccess)